# crashing when trying to free 3D array in C

Tags: c, arrays, malloc, free, dynamic-memory-allocation

#### Background

I have allocated space for a char*** array that stores parsed commands and arguments entered into my shell program.

Here are some example command line inputs:

```
ls -la
cd ..
/usr/bin/wc -l inputs/data/long
```

Here's how the char*** array stores the commands - it parses by white space:

`{{"ls", "-la"}, {"cd", ".."}, {"/usr/bin/wc", "-l", "inputs/data/long"}}`

Here's how I generate the char*** array:

```
/*
 * initializes history
 * returns array of pointers to arrays of pointers to char arrays
 */
char*** inithistory(){
    char*** history;
    history = (char***) calloc(HIST_SIZE, sizeof(char**));
    return history;
}

/*
 * adds a tokenized command and arguments to the history
 */
int addToHistory(char*** history, char** tokenized, int* argcnts, int argcnt, int cmdcnt) {
    if (cmdcnt >= HIST_SIZE) {
        cmdcnt = HIST_SIZE-1;

        // remove oldest element and shift others up
        for (int i = 0; i < HIST_SIZE-1; i++) {
            history[i] = history[i+1];
            argcnts[i] = argcnts[i+1];
        }
    }

    // add latest element
    history[cmdcnt] = tokenized;
    argcnts[cmdcnt] = argcnt;
    return 1;
}

/*
 * returns the length of a char array
 */
int lengthof(char* string) {
  int count = 0;
  char temp = string[0];
  while (temp) {
    temp = string[count];
    count++;
  }
  if (count==0) {
      return 0;
  }
  return count-1;
}

/*
 * returns array of pointers to char arrays containing parsed command and arguments e.g. {"ls", "-la"},
 * char* input is the command line input
 */
char** tokenize(char* input, int argc) {
  char* token;
  char** tokenized;
  tokenized = (char**) calloc(argc+1, sizeof(char*));
  token = strtok(input, " "); // tokenize user input
  int i = 0;
  while (token != NULL) {
    int length = lengthof(token);
    if (i == argc-1) {
      token[length-1] = '\0';
    }
    tokenized[i] = (char*) calloc(length, sizeof(char));
    tokenized[i] = token;
    token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i++;
  }
  tokenized[argc] = NULL;
  return tokenized;
}
```

#### Problem

When I try to free the char*** array above, I get the following error:

```
*** glibc detected *** cs475sh: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000000150f9b3 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x36bb075dee]
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x36bb078c3d]
cs475sh[0x4015e9]
cs475sh[0x400d37]
cs475sh[0x400bf0]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xfd)[0x36bb01ed1d]
cs475sh[0x400a59]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00402000 r-xp 00000000 00:14 12006791923606037921               /home/Documents/HW1/shell-handout/cs475sh
00601000-00602000 r--p 00001000 00:14 12006791923606037921               /home/Documents/HW1/shell-handout/cs475sh
00602000-00603000 rw-p 00002000 00:14 12006791923606037921               /home/Documents/HW1/shell-handout/cs475sh
0150f000-01530000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
36bac00000-36bac20000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 918063                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
36bae20000-36bae21000 r--p 00020000 fd:00 918063                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
36bae21000-36bae22000 rw-p 00021000 fd:00 918063                         /lib64/ld-2.12.so
36bae22000-36bae23000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
36bb000000-36bb18a000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 918804                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36bb18a000-36bb38a000 ---p 0018a000 fd:00 918804                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36bb38a000-36bb38e000 r--p 0018a000 fd:00 918804                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36bb38e000-36bb390000 rw-p 0018e000 fd:00 918804                         /lib64/libc-2.12.so
36bb390000-36bb394000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
36bd800000-36bd816000 r-xp 00000000 fd:00 918982                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
36bd816000-36bda15000 ---p 00016000 fd:00 918982                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
36bda15000-36bda16000 rw-p 00015000 fd:00 918982                         /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
7f1088000000-7f1088021000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f1088021000-7f108c000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
7f108c410000-7f108c413000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7f108c42f000-7f108c433000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffc6e541000-7ffc6e557000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffc6e55b000-7ffc6e55c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
Aborted
```

Here's how I free the array:

```
/*
 * char*** history is the array that needs to be freed,
 * int cmd is the number of parsed commands in history (char** pointers),
 * int* argcnts holds the number of arguments per command (each argument is 
 * char* - count includes the command itself) 
 */
void exitProg(int code, char*** history, int* argcnts, int cmdcnt) {
    if (!code) {
        exit(code);
    }
    if (!cmdcnt) {
        exit(code);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < cmdcnt; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < argcnts[i]; j++) {
            free(history[i][j]);
        }
        free(history[i]);
    }
    free(history);
    exit(code);
}
```

I know it's redundant to free memory before exiting the program, but it's required for the assignment.

I've noticed that the error is only given after attempting to execute `free(history[i][j]);`.

Comment: `tokenized[i] = (char*) calloc(length, sizeof(char)); tokenized[i] = token;` Oh, memory leak. By the way, what is `lengthof()`?

Comment: Please don't do this. It will be unmaintainable, it won't make any sense. You don't need a "3D array" and that's not what you have either. You need a 2D array of character pointers. `char* (*arr)[x][y] = malloc( sizeof(char*[x][y]) );`. See [Correctly allocating multi-dimensional arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42094465/correctly-allocating-multi-dimensional-arrays).

Comment: Not only is that a memory leak, it's a likely cause for the segfault.  You probably want the second of those statements to be `strcpy(tokenized[i], token);`.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe I missed that. Thanks!

@Lundin I had no idea I had been doing multi-dimensional arrays wrong. Thanks for the read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a memory leak as MikeCAT pointed out:

> tokenized[i] = (char*) calloc(length, sizeof(char)); tokenized[i] =
>   token; Oh, memory leak.

This problem was solved by with a simple strcpy as John Bollinger stated:

> Not only is that a memory leak, it's a likely cause for the segfault.
>   You probably want the second of those statements to be
>   strcpy(tokenized[i], token);

Freeing the memory now works without fault.